# Is there a best practice for managing isLoading state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm sorry for my English skills in advance.

Let's say I want to fetch data from server and render it on page load...the logic is something like this:

1. Page is loading and Preloader is shown (at this moment I send get request).
2. Data is fetched and sent to State.
3. Preloader disappears and data from state is rendered on a page.

My initial state looks like this:

```
const state = {
        data: [],
        isLoading: false
      }
```

I'm doing following (the code is about logic):

```
  function fetchData() {
    try {
      fetch(URL)
      dispatch({...state, isLoading: true})

          setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch({...state, data: data.payload, isLoading: false})
          }, 500);
        } catch (err) {
          dispatch({...state, isLoading: false})
        }
      }
```

Is that correct logic? I'm not sure if this is the best practice....maybe I should do it this way:

```
  function fetchData() {
    try {
      fetch(URL)
      dispatch({...state, isLoading: true})

      setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch({...state, data: data.payload})
      }, 500);
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({...state, isLoading: false})
    } finally {
      dispatch({...state, isLoading: false})
    }
}
```

So what is the best way to change isLoading state?

The third option which I'm thinking about is to create a separate state isLoading...I mean I will have to states:

```
  const state = {
    data: [],
  }

  const isLoadingState = {
    isLoading: false,
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand why there is any `setTimeout` involved.

Comment: This is an opinion based question. In the second approach, you don't need to set loading to false in the catch block as finally will be called even when there's an error.

Comment: @DaveNewton I think he's trying to replicate an async action

Comment: @DaveNewton without setTimeout the Preloader apprear and dissappear too quikly...it's litterally flickers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `isLoading: true` right before fetching.

[The finally-block will always execute after the try-block and catch-block(s) have finished executing. It always executes, regardless of whether an exception was thrown or caught.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#description)

So it depends on logic of your application, but it would be completely ok to avoid `isLoading: false` in `try` and `catch` blocks, and set it `false` just in the `finally` block.

```
 async function fetchData() {
    try {
      dispatch({...state, isLoading: true})
      const data = await fetch(URL)  

      dispatch({...state, data: data.payload})
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } finally {
      dispatch({...state, isLoading: false})
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to have your loading indicator update in your finally block:

```
function fetchData() {
    try {
      dispatch({...state, isLoading: true})
      fetch(URL)
      dispatch({...state})

      setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch({...state, data: data.payload})
      }, 500);
    } finally {
      dispatch({...state, isLoading: false})
    }
}
```

It's always going to finally block when your request is finished, so you don't need to repeatedly set it in your success or catch block.